# Passing options to the newenvironment

Tags: environments

I have a GrayBox environment defined as follows.

It is used `\begin{GrayBox}...\end{GrayBox}` or `\begin{GrayBox}[\textwidth]...\end{GrayBox}`, that is, it can pass optional parameter to the environment.

I guess #1 is the setup for default value, and #2 is for setup for the value given.

### Question

How is #2 possible? I mean, is it LaTeX's rule that if `#1` is not given, the default value in `[]` is used instead? Is there any reference about this? Is the same technique can be applied to `\newcommand`?

```
\newlength{\RoundedBoxWidth}
\newsavebox{\GrayRoundedBox}
\newenvironment{GrayBox}[1][\dimexpr\textwidth-4.5ex]% **** #1
   {\setlength{\RoundedBoxWidth}{\dimexpr#1} **** #2
    \begin{lrbox}{\GrayRoundedBox}
       \begin{minipage}{\RoundedBoxWidth}}%
   {   \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
       \draw node[draw=black,fill=black!10,rounded corners,%
             inner sep=2ex,text width=\RoundedBoxWidth]%
             {\usebox{\GrayRoundedBox}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}}
```

Comment: Why is there a `???` in the question, BTW? Was it intentional or some Unicode char that got corrupted?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR : Just a mark to ask some question.

Comment: BTW: you might want to add a `\relax` after the expression evaluated by `\dimexpr` just to be on the safe side, even if it's not strictly necessary here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is LaTeX's rule that if the optional argument is not present, then `#1` takes on the default value.  That is,

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{hello}[1][world]{\noindent Hello #1, }{Bye now!\\}
\begin{document}
  \begin{hello}
    nice to meet you.
  \end{hello}
  \begin{hello}[Bob]
    glad you could make it.
  \end{hello}
\end{document}
```

will produce

> Hello world, nice to meet you. Bye now!
>      Hello Bob, glad you could make it. Bye now!

as its output.  The same is true for commands defined with optional parameters, as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\hi}[1][world!]{\noindent Hello #1}
\begin{document}
  \hi \\
  \hi[Bob]
\end{document}
```

which results in the output

> Hello world!
>      Hello Bob

Comment: Your example mixes environments and commands!  Whilst environments _are_ just fancy commands, would it be okay to edit it (either you or I) in to two examples: one an environment (with `\begin{hello} ... \end{hello}` and one a command?

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I did that!  Thanks for pointing it out Andrew, hopefully this version is a little more suitable.

Comment: Yup, looks fine now.