# Using optional argument in closing statement of new environment

Tags: macros, environments, optional-arguments

The answer [969/29410](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/969/29410) showed that it is possible to use optional arguments in environment definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{hello}[1][world]{\noindent Hello #1, }{Bye now!\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{hello}[Bob]\end{hello}
\end{document}
```

This works fine and produces

> Hello Bob, Bye now!

Why is it that the optional argument cannot be used in the closing statement?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{hello}[1][world]{\noindent Hello, }{Bye now, #1!\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{hello}[Bob]\end{hello}
\end{document}
```

> line 2: Illegal parameter number in definition of \endhello.
>   ...][world]{\noindent Hello, }{Bye now, #1!\}
>
> line 4: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal
>   mode. \begin{hello}[Bob]\end{hello}
>
> line 4: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph

Comment: You can't use arguments in the `\end{part}` of the environment. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460014/134574). You can, however, do `\def\MyEnvOptArg{#1}` in the `\begin` part and use `\MyEnvOptArg` instead of `#1` in the `\end` part.

Comment: Or use `xparse` or `environ`…